# Holding Key down for a period of time

Tags: java, key

I was wondering if there is any way to hold down a key for a period of time in Java. The problem is if you use Robot.keyPress () it repeatedly presses the key, whereas I want it held down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`robot.keyPress` presses the key and `robot.keyRelease` releases it. Therefore if you find a way to spend the requisite time between those two calls (e.g. robot.delay(), sleep() or wait()) then you should be sorted.